# Pass parameter in resources?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to pass an `id` in `routes.web.php` to a controller.

I have done in `routes/web.php`

```
Route::resources([
    'projects/{id}' => 'ProjectsController',
]);
```

and in `app/Http/Controllers/ProjectsController.php` :

```
class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct($id=999)
    {
        dd($id);
    }
}
```

which not showing the id passed in `http://localhost:8000/projects/12` but showing `999`

Could someone please help me why the passed id is not getting into the controller ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: parameter should not be in construct, should be defined in restful API. For example ```function index($id)```

Comment: @caoglish Thank you. I added in construct because I want the id in every function of the class. Is there a way to get with it ?

Comment: Just put $id in every function then. There are no shortcut

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a request parameter from the controller constructor you can inject `Illuminate\Http\Request` and then access the request parameter. Ex:

```
class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.

if you want to pass id to controller

```
  Route::get('/path/{id}', array('uses' => 
  'YourController@yourFunction'));
```

then in controller

```
    class YourController extends Controller
    {
      public function yourFunction($id)
       {
         return $id;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to pass id in your route you will use like this

```
Route::get('/url_path/{id}', array('uses' => 
  'YourController@yourFunction'));
```

//where id pass is compulsory

or else

```
Route::get('/url_path/{id?}', array('uses' => 
  'YourController@yourFunction'));
```

//where id pass is Optional
then in controller

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
  public function yourFunction($id)
   {
     return $id;
   }
}
```